# How to identify ARIMA model parameters

Tags: time-series, matlab, model-selection

I am trying to build ARIMA model, I have 144 terms in my standardized time series, which represent residuals form original time series. This residuals, on which I would like to build ARIMA model, are obtained when I subtracted linear trend and periodical component from original time series, so residuals are stochastic component.

Because of that subtraction I modeled residuals like stationary series (d=0), so model is ARIMA(p,d,q)=ARIMA(?,0,?).

ACF and PACF functions of my residuals are not very clear as cases in literature for identification ARIMA models, and when I choose parameters p and q according to criteria that they are last values outside of confidence interval, I got values p=109, q=97. Matlab gave me error for this case:

> Error using arima/estimate (line 386)
>
> Input response series has an insufficient number of observations.

On the other side, when I am looking only to N/4 length of time series for identifying p and q parameters, I got p=36, q=34. Matlab gave me error for this case

> Warning: Nonlinear inequality constraints are active; standard errors may be inaccurate.
>
> In arima.estimate at 1113
>
> Error using arima/validateModel (line 1306)
>
> The non-seasonal autoregressive polynomial is unstable.
>
> Error in arima/setLagOp (line 391)
>      Mdl = validateModel(Mdl);
>
> Error in arima/estimate (line 1181)
>     Mdl = setLagOp(Mdl, 'AR' , LagOp([1 -coefficients(iAR)' ], 'Lags', [0 LagsAR ]));

How do I need to correct identify p and q parameters and what is wrong here? And wwhat does it mean in this partial autocorrelation diagram, why are last values so big?

[image: ACF of time series]
[image: PACF of time series]